# ReactJS: draggable not in same position after refreshing page

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, position, draggable

I am saving the positions of my Draggables to localStorage so that they remain the same position after refreshing the page.

However, after refreshing the page, they are not in the same position as before, but somewhat rightward and downward than the original position.

And I've just found that the values printed in the `console.log()` changes every time even though I didn't change the position of the component (just click on it without dragging). For example:

```
new x: 153, new y: 185
new x: 221, new y: 229
new x: 184, new y: 210
```

The above log is what I have after clicking the same draggable three times. The draggable should remain on the same position, but their x and y values change every time.

App.js

```js
function App() {
    const [myComponents, setMyComponents] = useState([]);
    
    // read data from localStorage
    useEffect(() => {
        const savedItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('app-data'));
        if (savedItems) {
            setMyComponents(savedItems);
        }
    }, []);

    // save data to localStorage
    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem('app-data', JSON.stringify(myComponents));
    }, [myComponents]);

    // setMyComponents to the new list with the modified item (target)
    function updatePosition(target) {
        const newComponents = myComponents.map((component) => {
            if (target.id === component.id) {
                return target;
            } else {
                return component;
            }
        });
        setMyComponents(newComponents);
        console.log("new x: " + target.x + ", new y: " + target.y);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            {myComponents.map((n) => <MyComponent myCompo={n} updatePosition={updatePosition} />)}
        </div>
    );
}
```

MyComponent.js

```js
import Draggable from 'react-draggable';

function MyComponent({myCompo, updatePosition}) {

    // update x and y of myCompo when dragging is stopped
    function handleStop(dragElement) {
        myCompo.x = dragElement.x;
        myCompo.y = dragElement.y;
        updatePosition(myCompo);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Draggabble
              onStop={handleStop}
              defaultPosition={{x: myCompo.x, y: myCompo.y}}
              positionOffset={{ x: '-50%', y: '-50%' }}>
                <div className="someChild"></div>
            </Draggable>
        </div>
    );
}
```

MyComponent.css

```css
.someChild {
    width: 240px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

This part of css is written before I try to store the position of the draggable. I want the component to be placed at the center of the window. Then I find `position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%;` in css and `positionOffset={{ x: '-50%', y: '-50%' }}` in Draggable props can help me centering the component.

Don't know if the problem in storing the position is related to this piece of css and positionOffset.
I have a button that add a new copy of MyComponent, and I hope the newly created MyComponent can be placed at the center before being dragged around.

And the data in my components are stored in this format

```json
{
    id: 0,
    body: "some text",
    x: 0,
    y: 0
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found where the problem is. The `event` argument in the function `handleStop()` was missing.

After adding `event` it works.

```js
function handleStop(event, dragElement) {
    myCompo.x = dragElement.x;
    myCompo.y = dragElement.y;
    updatePosition(myCompo);
}
```